# asp.net: authentication

Tags: asp.net

When I upload my asp.net web application to the server and access to the url link, it is asking for the authentication... if I dont, I got this error message:

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via , the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user.

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

---

What should I change in the web.config file in order to get this working as locally?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure you converted the directory to an application in IIS?

- Browse to directory in IIS directory tree
- Right click and select "Convert to Application"
- Select application pool, and convert

Comment: This is on the server, I can not do this... It is managed with Plesk!